# How to use block model and controller in Magento

Tags: magento

I am new in Magento, I need to create a custom module in Magento.
I tried the following code without success.
Is  there any solution for that? Please provide me and share some book link and Youtube link.

The code file as 
app/code/local
-Baobaz
-Arithmetic
It contains Block, controllers, etc, Model.
In the `controllers` folder there is controller file named 
IntegerController.php and here the code:

```
<?php
class Baobaz_Arithmetic_IntegerController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function multiplyAction(){
         $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

The config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <baobaz_arithmetic>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </baobaz_arithmetic>
    </modules>
   <frontend>
        <routers>
            <arithmetic>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Baobaz_Arithmetic</module>
                    <frontName>arithmetic</frontName>
                </args>
            </arithmetic>
        </routers>
      <layout>
            <updates>
                <arithmetic>
                    <file>arithmetic.xml</file>
                </arithmetic>
            </updates>
        </layout>  
    </frontend>
   <global>
    <blocks>
      <arithmetic>
        <class>Baobaz_arithmetic_Block</class>
      </arithmetic>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <arithmetic>
        <class>Baobaz_arithmetic_Model</class>
      </arithmetic>
    </models>
  </global>
 </config>
```

`Model/Arithmetic.php` code:

```
<?php

class Baobaz_Arithmetic_Model_Arithmetic extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
  public function getRecentProducts() {
    $products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
                -­>getCollection()
                ­->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ­->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
                ­->setPageSize(5);
    return $products;
  }
}
```

`Block/Arithmetic.php` code:

```
<?php

class Baobaz_Arithmetic_Block_Arithmetic extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
  public function getRecentProducts() {
    // call model to fetch data
    $arr_products = array();

    $products = Mage::getModel('arithmetic/arithmetic')->getRecentProducts();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
      $arr_products[] = array(
        'id' => $product-­>getId(),
        'name' => $product­->getName(),
        'url' => $product­->getProductUrl(),
      );
    }

   return $arr_products;
  }
}
```

`app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/arithmetic.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <arithmetic_integer_multiply>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="arithmetic/arithmetic" name="arithmetic/arithmetic" template="arithmetic/integer/multiply.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </arithmetic_integer_multiply>
</layout>
```

`arithmetic/integer/multiply.phtml` code:

```
<?php

$products = $this­->getRecentProducts();
?>
<div id="product_list">
  <h1>Recent Products</h1>
  <?php if (is_array($products) && count($products)) { ?>
    <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
      <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $product['url'] ?>"><?php echo $product['name'] ?></a>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

but I got the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: thisÂ­  in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/arithmetic/integer/multiply.phtml on line 3

#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/arithmetic/integer/multiply.phtml(3): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/opt/lampp/htdo...', 3, Array)
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#7 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(605): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(549): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#9 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#10 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...')
#11 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#12 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(886): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#16 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/local/Baobaz/Arithmetic/controllers/IntegerController.php(6): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#17 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Baobaz_Arithmetic_IntegerController->multiplyAction()
#18 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('multiply')
#19 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/index.php(93): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I copy&paste the mentioned line (...multiply.phtml on line 3) into my editor, it reveals that theres a special character behind the "$this"? Try deleting that character.

```
products = $this­[here]­->getRecentProducts();
```

Comment: thanks sir please provide some link also for magneto tutorial

Comment: I liked Alan Storm's: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_for_php_developers